# Styled Components - use styled component as base for another component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I thought this was possible with styled components

Using the first styled Component `Block` as the bases for another component like

`export const BlockOne = styled.Block`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Block = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
`

export const BlockOne = styled.Block`
  background: yellow;
`

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Block/>
      <BlockOne/>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Is there a way to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, like [this](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles)

```
export const BlockOne = styled(Block)`
  background: yellow;
`
```

styled-component only has basic components (tags such as div, span, etc.) as attributes. For anything else, you pass it as a prop.

If you pass a custom component to it, make sure that it accepts a className and that it passes it down to a div or something:

```
const MyComponent = ({className}) => {
  return <div className={className}></div> // styled-component will use this classname to apply the style
}

export const MyStyledComponent = styled(MyComponent)`
  background: yellow;
`
```

Else it would have no effect.